# Stuff looks really small when I open it on my phone, how can I fix this with CSS

Tags: html, css

So, I know the principles behind responsive design, the @media stuff at all that.  But I have a project with very simple html.  Project :

```
    <html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RegEx Profanity Filter</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>


    <body>
 <p>Insert profanity laced rant here:</p>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">

</textarea>

<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="check()">

<div id = "filtered"></div>

</body>
```

When I open them on my laptop, they look fine.  All the content in Regex Profanity filter takes up about 1/3rd of the width of the screen.  But when I open it in my iphone with Safari, that's still true, which makes everything look really small.

I even tried wrapping everything in the first project in a div called "everything" and setting its width to 100% when the screen is 900px or less.  I didn't expect that to work and it didn't.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You are missing the meta tag in your head: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` that makes this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the viewport through the `<meta>` tag in `<head>`.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

This line of code is telling the browser to set the width of the viewport to match the width of the device's screen, and to initially display the web page at a 100% zoom level. This helps ensure that the web page is displayed properly and responsively on different devices.

**name="viewport":** This attribute defines the purpose of the metadata, which is to specify the viewport settings.

**width=device-width:** This part sets the width of the viewport to the width of the device's screen.

**initial-scale=1.0:** This part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded. A scale of 1.0 means that the page is displayed at 100% zoom level, without any initial zooming or scaling.

[MDN - Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) 
[W3Schools - Responsive Web Design - The Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)